# Error 403 when I submit the register form in spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am learning spring boot and write a register form, but when I run it in idea and submit the form, the browser occurs

> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
>   Forbidden

I create the project by using spring initializr in idea, choose web+jpa+h2+thymeleaf.
I defined an Entity called Worker and set error messages in ValidationMessages.properties, here is the Worker entity

```
@Entity
public class Worker implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialversionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 16, message = "{username.size}")
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "{firstName.size}")
    private String firstname;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "{lastName.size")
    private String lastname;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 25,message = "{password.size}")
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "{profession,size}")
    private String profession;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    //UserDetails methods


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("WORKER"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and WorkersRepository

```
public interface WorkersRepository extends JpaRepository<Worker, String> {
Worker findByUsername(String username);
```

}

I have added spring security, and wrote the config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WorkersRepository workersRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/submit").access("hasRole('WORKER')")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .tokenValiditySeconds(4838400)
            .key("workerKey");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws      Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws       UsernameNotFoundException {
                return workersRepository.findByUsername(username);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If the register input occurs error, the controller returns the registerForm.html to ask user to input again correctly. If the register has no error, the controller redirects to "/", a simple welcome.html. But whether the input is correct or not, I always get the error 403. When I input`http://localhost:8080/`, I can get the welcome.html,which is a simple page with "welcome!" words. My controller is

```
private WorkersRepository workersRepository;

@Autowired
public  WorkingHoursController(
        WorkersRepository workersRepository) {
    this.workersRepository = workersRepository;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcomePage() {
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(new Worker());
    return "registerForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registrationProcessing(@Valid Worker worker, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes model) {
    if(errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "registerForm";
    }
    workersRepository.save(worker);
    model.addAttribute("username", worker.getUsername());
    model.addFlashAttribute("worker", worker);
    return "redirect:/";
}
...
```

I wrote the registerForm.html using thymeleaf and add error validations. My registerForm.html is

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" th:object="${worker}">
<div class="errors" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
    <ul>
        <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}"
            th:text="${err}">Input is in correct.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please register</h1>

<!-- input username -->
<label for="inputUsername" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}? 'error'">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="inputUsername" th:field="*{username}" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}? 'error form-control':'form-control'" placeholder="Username">
...
<!-- input password -->
<label for="inputPassword" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}? 'error'">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" th:field="*{password}" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}? 'error form-control':'form-control'" placeholder="Password">
<div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
```

Before I add validations in thymeleaf and add spring security, everything seems to work properly.

Comment: did you add configuration for in your `properties` file for `tymeleaf` ?

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon Yes I did, I can see it in pom.xml. I can see the registerForm.html in the browser correctly, it uses css file like `<link th:href="@{/register.css}" rel="stylesheet">` correctly., which is thymeleaf grammer.

Comment: in that case, it can be said that the problem occurs for `SecurityConfig`.  There might be some configuration issues.

Comment: Is this `http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/submit").access("hasRole('WORKER')")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()`  the problem? The `.anyRequest().permitAll` does not allow the  "/" request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did not put any action inside form tag. Perhaps that's why you are getting error. Put action inside form tag like this one

```
<form class="form-signin" action="#" th:action="@{/register}" method="post" th:object="${worker}">
```

Comment: Thank you, It works! By the way,  I wrote the form by reading the book __spring in action__. In this book it did not have the `th:action`, what the difference between these?

Comment: You are using Thymeleaf. Syntax are little different for thymeleaf. Check https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html this one.

Answer (score 1):

Please check once whether role should be "WORKER" or "ROLE_WORKER" according to your Spring Security JAR version. Also disable the CSRF in your application, and set global CORS config to accept all requests.

Comment: Thanks god I came across this comment!

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your config class

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http 
        .csrf() 
        .disable() 
}
```

This is security stuff, it prevents hackers from using your open account credentials without your permission i.e. you get an email that say click here (that click takes your user info to another site without your consent). only use the above for dev.
For pro; add a csrf token as a hidden input on your form. this token is in your spring server.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```